# Local Development for Hadoop getting nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.acc

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a starter on local development for MapReduce and I added all Jars and the boilerplate and everything work fine but when I run the map reduce it gives bellow error....

```
2017-02-10 18:59:46,754 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-02-10 18:59:46,912 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1173)) - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-02-10 18:59:46,913 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(76)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2017-02-10 18:59:47,654 WARN  [main] mapreduce.JobResourceUploader (JobResourceUploader.java:uploadFiles(171)) - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-02-10 18:59:47,664 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(283)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-02-10 18:59:47,953 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(198)) - number of splits:1
2017-02-10 18:59:48,169 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:printTokens(287)) - Submitting tokens for job: job_local2065581035_0001
2017-02-10 18:59:48,281 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(249)) - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-Zack K Miah/mapred/staging/Omer K Niah2065581035/.staging/job_local2065581035_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at summerize.main.run(main.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at summerize.main.main(main.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

and bellow is my code for main class that combine mpper and reducer... I have not installed Hadoop my system and that is not my goal but to only develop and learn MapReduce job with the Hadoop jars.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import java.awt.*;


public class main extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {



        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
        job.setJobName("Average");
        job.setJarByClass(main.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(reduce.class);

        Path inputFilePath = new Path("C:\\javaDEV\\MyFirstMapReduce\\data\\input\\sens.txt");
        Path outputFilePath = new Path ("C:\\javaDEV\\MyFirstMapReduce\\data\\output");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\winutils");

       // System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\hadoop\\hadoop-2.7.3");
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run( new main(), args);

        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

}
```

thanks for the help in advance.

regards